# Using the javascript Object.defineProperty to create data binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding

I have been playing with the javascript Object.defineProperty to create data binding. Here is my example.I don't understand why the data's property: name updates when i change the input2's value in the html.Thx very much.

```
<input type="text" id="text1" />
<input type="text" id="text2" />

var input1 = document.querySelector("#text1");
var input2 = document.querySelector("#text2");
var data = {};
Object.defineProperty(data, "name", {
  configurable: true,
  get: function(){
      console.log(1111);
      return input1.value
  },
  set: function(newValue){
      console.log(222);
    input1.value = newValue;
    input2.value = newValue;
  }
})
data.name = "sss";
input1.onchange = function(){
  console.log(33333)
  data.name = data.name;
}
input2.onchange = function(){
  input1.value = this.value;
  console.log(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When the user changes `input2`, `input2.onchange()` is called.
2. `input2.onchange()` sets `input1.value`.
3. Since the `get()` method returns `input1.value`, referencing `data.name` returns the new `input1.value`.